# useMutation return value identity

Tags: apollo, apollo-client

Should the value have a stable identity if the mutation has not been called? I could not find the information in docs. I am using apollo-client v3.

I have a `useEffect` with mutation result as a dependency and it was triggered very often. When I used loading and data from the result as a dependency then `useEffect` fired only after the mutation.

this would fire very often

```
const [update, mutationResult] = useMutation(document);
useEffect(() => { ... }, [mutationResult]);
```

this would fire only after calling the update function

```
const [update, { data, loading }] = useMutation(document);
useEffect(() => { ... }, [data, loading]);
```

Comment: Why do you want to use ```useMutation``` in ```useEffect```? It can cause infinity rendering

Comment: @Michael I want to react to mutation results rather than refetching everything again. It could be that the mutation result object is created each time and it is intended.

Comment: Can you show more code?

Comment: I was not using cache and relied on results from mutation/subscription to update the local state. The initial value of this state would be from a query. I was also not aware of the `onComplete` callback that I could use instead of `useEffect`.

I am trying to make use of the cache now so I can get rid of some hooks. I managed to get it working for fields with an `id`. However, I have some types that have only 1 instance and it feels wrong to give them an `id`. Is there a way to update those from mutations/subscriptions without manually updating the cache after their execution?

Comment: Sorry, I can't get your idea. What do you want to do after the execution of mutations/ subscriptions?

Comment: Sorry for the late replies. I am just experimenting with the whole GraphQL. I have tightly coupled queries, mutations and subscriptions and I wanted to keep the cache up to date. I went for using `cache.writeQuery`. It would be nicer if I could identify query cache in the same way as using `id` field in types. So they would update automatically when mutation or subscription with the same args returns something.

Comment: When you update a field in your data (like you change a field name in a user object of the user list), Apollo will automatically update your data. But, when you receive new data (like a new user) which is not contained in user list, you have to use ```cache.writeQuery``` to update your user list.